# How big of a roast do I need

Tags: raw-meat

We are making prime rib for dinner on Christmas Day, were having 25 people how many pounds of roast do I need

Comment: Welcome to Seasoned Advice SE! So... when's dinner? (sounds yummy)

Answer (score 3):

A normal serving of meat is 200-250 grams per person. In American units, about half a pound per person. Times 25 and you will have a good estimate. If there are a lot of sides or multiple courses you can decrease it a little.

Answer (score -2):

How much would you like to eat (assuming you eat reasonable portions) Times that by 25 and you should be fine.